# dotnet build for Ubuntu includes standard DLLs

Tags: .net, ubuntu, dll, build

I have migrated a .NET Framework solution to .NET 6.0. The solution is run on Ubuntu (previously using Mono).

I have set the `RuntimeIdentifier` to `ubuntu.22.04-x64`.
This way the complete build gets written to one folder `net6.0/ubuntu.22.04-x64`, and I don't get a `runtimes` folder with many Linux distro subfolders (I reference `Mono.Posix.NETStandard.dll`).

Now when I build the solution using a plain `dotnet build .\name.sln`, all the standard DLLs (`System.dll` and 100 others) are copied to the output folder.
This does not happen if omit `RuntimeIdentifier`.

I am not building this as a self-contained application, i.e. I'll have dotnet-runtime installed on Ubuntu.

How can I control this?

Here is part of the solution's main project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ubuntu.22.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <TargetZone>LocalIntranet</TargetZone>
    <GenerateManifests>false</GenerateManifests>
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
    <ReleaseVersion>4.4.0</ReleaseVersion>
    <UseMSBuildEngine>False</UseMSBuildEngine>
    <NoWin32Manifest>False</NoWin32Manifest>
    <RunPostBuildEvent>OnBuildSuccess</RunPostBuildEvent>
    <NoStdLib>False</NoStdLib>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>false</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
    <OutputPath>..\..\build\solutionname</OutputPath>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <StartAction>Project</StartAction>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU' ">
    <BaseAddress>4194304</BaseAddress>
    <RegisterForComInterop>False</RegisterForComInterop>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Auto</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
.....
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers" Version="0.4.355802">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SharpZipLib.NETStandard" Version="1.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Spring.Core" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to fix this:

I need to explicitly set `--self-contained false` in the build command.
Or, when publishing, set `--no-self-contained`.

This is because if a `RuntimeIdentifier` is set, dotnet will assume `true` as the default for self-contained, see the [dotnet build specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#options).